# Python regex: How to specify an optional match (for potentially empty sub expression)?

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to match the following sets of input:

```
foo_abc_bar  
foo_bar
```

and get "abc" or an empty string as the result.

So this is the regular expression I wrote:

`r'foo_(abc|)[_|]bar'`

But for some reason, this does not match with the second string that I have given.

On further inspection, I found that `[_|]` does not match an empty string.

So, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make `abc_` optional, you could use the [question mark operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
(abc_)?
```

Thus, the entire regex becomes:

```
r'foo_(abc_)?bar'
```

With this regex, the second underscore (if present) will become part of the capture group. If you don't want that, you could either remove it post-match with `.rstrip('_')` or use a slightly more complex regex:

```
r'foo_(?:(abc)_)?bar'
```

> I found that `[_|]` does not match an empty string.

That's right. Square brackets denote a character group. The `[_|]` would match exactly one underscore or exactly one vertical bar, and nothing else. In other words, the vertical bar loses its special meaning when it appears inside a character group.

Comment: Might be the best answer, but doesn't *exactly* match what the question asked for because when you match `re.match(r'foo_(abc_)?bar', 'foo_abc_bar').group(1)` is `'abc_'` and `re.match(r'foo_(abc_)?bar', 'foo_bar').group(1)` is `None`. I wasn't able to do much better with nested groupings. I could match the exact strings (including empty string) but the positions (group subscript) varied between the two cases.

Comment: @jimhark: It's pretty trivial to address this. I didn't want to do it to keep the answer brief. However, now that this has come up in the comments, I've expanded the answer.

Comment: `r'foo_(?:(abc)_)?bar'`, nice. I'll remember that. Much better than what I came up with. Now correctly handles `'foo_abc_bar'` by returning `'abc'`. However `'foo_bar'` still returns None. I still think (even more) this is the best answer and the calling code should just deal with the None value. +1

Comment: @jimhark: I personally would use `r'foo_(abc_)?bar'` and post-process the result with simple Python logic. I think that would give the clearest solution.

Comment: I agree unless he has a set of regexs he needs to treat uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a string pattern like this

```
xxx_xxx_xxx
xxx_xxx
```

then you need

```
([A-Za-z]{3})((_[A-Za-z]{3})+)?
```

but this will work also

```
r'foo(_abc)?_bar'
```

`?` means optional (*may or may not match*).